# How does one go about answering (cleaning up) unanswered questions without downvotes?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I'm trying to go through old unanswered questions on Stack Overflow and finding questions that by now are most likely completely irrelevent, because they were user specific and the user is gone and my idea of making it answered is to answer it to the best of my ability. But upon doing so there'll be a flood of random downvotes on my answer which hurts me cause I've only got ~100 rep.

Should I just flag the posts? I'm not able to downvote for another 50 rep and there's over 698k unanswered questions... that's crazy!

Example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108649/how-to-take-correct-shift-time-in-24-hours-clock-in-c/

**Related:** On some old posts the user is grayed out, does this mean their account has been deleted? What happens with answers to those questions?
Example: [Redirect domain.com/folder to folder.domain.com permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040200/redirect-domain-com-folder-to-folder-domain-com-permanently/)

Comment: If the question is acceptable then I see no reason to do anything to it except perhaps clarify/answer it. It might still be useful for future viewers even when the asker is long gone.

Comment: Well this was a two part question, the first bit was what to do about posts that wont be of any use to anyone else, like the arbitrary code in the first example. and the second question was what the faded username and image represented? (hasn't been on, banned, deleted account, all of these?)

Comment: For the first question, I'd say, you can just answer it *carefully*, since OP won't clarify his question anymore, to make sure that your answer really tries to solve his problem (at least when you or anyone try your code). Yes, the faded username means the account is no more already, presumably deleted. But that doesn't mean the question won't be useful. Future readers may stumble upon this question and may upvote your answer if they find it helpful. *At worst*, nobody will search and view this question. I don't see why people will downvote your answer if it really answers the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your contribution. I agree that it's a good criterium if the question can be useful for someone else. If it is, try to answer the question. If it isn't flag it, downvote it, vote to close ...

If the question is good, don't mind if the user is no longer active. If it's bad and the user is gone, there is no point to give an answer.